# bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: The operation couldn’t be completed. Loading throttled

Tags: objective-c, iad, adbannerview

I am getting the error mentioned in the title.

Here is the situation:

- bannerView loads
- applicationDidEnterBackground (I hit home button)
- applicationWillEnterForeground (I re-enter application)
- I send HTTP asynchronous request to acquire authToken from my backend API.
- Before connectionDidFinishLoading delegate method is called, I get
  the error
- Then, connectionDidFinishLoading is called
- bannerView loads.

It seems like iAd framework wants to send an asynchronous request around the same time I do.

I haven't found any information on this error.  Any ideas?